# Flutter : how save list of dynamic to shared preference

Tags: list, flutter, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save a list of data to shared preference and read these articles but don't works with me :

[Flutter save List with shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246541/flutter-save-list-with-shared-preferences)

[Shared Preferences in Flutter cannot save and read List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55545326/shared-preferences-in-flutter-cannot-save-and-read-list)

I have this list :

```
var list =[
       {
          "id" : 1,
          "name" : "ali"
        },
        {
          "id" : 2,
          "name" : "jhon"
        }
      ];
```

I tried this :

```
setList() async {
    Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    prefs.setStringList('list', list);
  }
```

I get this error : `The argument type 'List<Map<String, Object>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<String>'`

Comment: im thinking about how you going to retrive them ?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because your `list` is of type `Map<String, Object>` and not a `String`. To fix this you can use [jsonEncode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonEncode.html) method which converts it into a `String`

```
Future<void> setList() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final List<String> jsonList = list.map((item) => jsonEncode(item)).toList();
  prefs.setStringList('list', jsonList);
}
```

If you now want to retrieve this list you have to use [jsonDecode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html) to convert it back to a `Map<String, Object>`.

```
List<Map<String, Object>> getList() async {
  final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final List<String> jsonList = prefs.getStringList('list')
  final List<Map<String, Object> list = jsonList.map((item) => jsonDecode(item)).toList();
  return list;
}
```